# using index.php in subfolder redirects and how many in htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

The domain has subfolders for each location and there is an index.php file in each location folder.  I have been advised that I need to get rid of all links and references to "index.php" and am not sure how this works with redirects.  This is not something I normally work with.

1. Which one is correct?

   ```
   Redirect 301 /charlottenc.html http://teamlocksmith.com/charlotte/index.php

   Redirect 301 /charlottenc.html http://teamlocksmith.com/charlotte/ 

   Redirect 301 /charlottenc.html http://teamlocksmith.com/charlotte
   ```
2. Are both of these needed?  All three are showing as crawl errors.

   ```
   Redirect 301 /fortlauderdale/index.php http://teamlocksmith.com/fort-lauderdale/index.php

   Redirect 301 /fortlauderdale/ http://teamlocksmith.com/fort-lauderdale/index.php

   Redirect 301 /fortlauderdale http://teamlocksmith.com/fort-lauderdale/index.php
   ```

I had about 300 or so crawl errors to moved pages and thought it would be a good idea to redirect all of them to the most relevant page.  I figured it was easier to use the htaccess file rather than a redirecting page for each.  So my first attempt worked but took a huge performance hit.  So I went through and took out redirects I don't think we really need.  So my question is if an htaccess file only contains redirects is it the number of them or something else causing the performance (load time) problem.

Comment: Right part of the URL will be appended to the redirected URL. So `Redirect 301 /fortlauderdale http://teamlocksmith.com/fort-lauderdale` also append index.php.

Comment: It will be better if you provide some examples of what URLs you are trying to redirect and what would be those target URLs?

Comment: I am trying to redirect pages that used to be located in a fortlauderdale folder (no longer there) to different files now located in a fort-Lauderdale folder.  In some cases the links to the older "pages" or folders that are no longer there like teamlocksmith.com/fortlauderdale others point to teamlocksmith.com/fortlauderdale/ and others point to teamlocksmith.com/fortlauderdale/index.php

Comment: The other question is which is the correct way to point to an index.php file.  I was advised not actually use index.php in the url teamlocksmith.com/fort-Lauderdale/index.php because it will cause the file be a duplicate of teamlocksmith.com/fort-Lauderdale/

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
DirectorySlash On
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^fortlauderdale(/.*)?$ /fort-Lauderdale$1 [L,NC,R=301]

# remove index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```

Comment: Would it be possible to do this for all of the different index.php files in all the 100 folders?

Comment: Can you provide example of other redirects?

Comment: You need to have separate 301 rules for these cases as paths are all different.

Comment: Redirect 301 /fort-worth/residential-locksmith-fort-worth-texas.php http://teamlocksmith.com/fort-worth/index.php
Redirect 301 /fort-worth/terms.php http://teamlocksmith.com/terms.php
Redirect 301 /fort-worth-tx http://teamlocksmith.com/fort-worth/index.php
Redirect 301 /fort-worth-tx/ http://teamlocksmith.com/fort-worth/index.php

Comment: Okay. Thank you.  I will get to writing them.  :)

Comment: If it worked out can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.